# System crashed during upgrading 16.10

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, mount

I have a recently done an upgrade of lastest version (Installing with live-usb keeping the home directory). But when i restart the computer, it's like i installed ubuntu by deleting all.

There is an partition /dev/sda2 that can not be mount and i don't know why.
[Link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDPzZ.png)

The return of `fdisk -l`

```
Disque /dev/sda : 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 octets, 976773168 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0f55a12e

Périphérique Amorçage     Start       Fin  Secteurs   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1    *             2048 960233471 960231424 457.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2             960235518 976771071  16535554   7.9G  5 Étendue
/dev/sda5             960235520 976771071  16535552   7.9G 82 partition d'échang

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Can somebody help me i don't understand ?

Comment: Did it crash, or did you wipe it? It sounds like you tried to upgrade from a LiveCD and that overwrote your Ubuntu installation. If you didn't keep backups then you're pretty much screwed.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Yes it crashed. To be more precise the system freezes during installation of the update, so I tried to cancel it and restart the computer but I think that something was already corrupted. so I tried reinstalling all properly with a USB drive bootable.

Comment: @PatrickNegus unfortunely, there is no backup..

Comment: Ok. So, you cancelled the installation and restarted the computer. If you have sensitive data, boot into a LiveCD and transfer those files to an external USB or hard drive. Then, wipe your disk and reinstall. If Ubuntu is corrupt and you don't have a backup then there aren't many options left.